# How many elements of $S_5$ send the set $\{2,4\}$ into the set $\{2,4\} ?$

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

How many elements of $S_5$ send the set $\{2,4\}$ into the set $\{2,4\} ?$

**My attempt** :let $\sigma\in S_5 $ be a permutation which send the set $\{2,4\}$ into the set $\{2,4\} $.Since $\sigma$ is injective  so we  have

$\sigma(2)=4$

$\sigma(4)=2$

$\sigma(4)=4$

$\sigma(2)=2$

$\implies$  there  are  $2$ elements of $S_5 $ which send the set $\{2,4\}$ into the set $\{2,4\} $

Comment: Hint: there are 2!=2 ways to send {2, 4} to {2, 4} as you mention, and 3!=6 ways to send {1, 3, 5} to {1, 3, 5}.

Comment: You have more, you're not counting what $\sigma$ could do to the other elements {1,3,5}.

Comment: @ItsMe question is about  $\{2, 4\}$ to $\{2, 4\}$    **NOT** {1, 2, 5} to {1, 2, 5}

Comment: $\sigma$ is a permutation in $S^5$ (not $S^2$) so you have to study his possible behavior in {1,2,3,4,5} (not only {2,4}).

Comment: Meaning, are you saying that $\sigma(3)=2$ @Bongo but question is about $\{2,4\}$ to$ \{2,4\}$.What is the purpose of taking  $\{1,3,5\}?$

Comment: Do you know what the elements of $S_5$ are?

Comment: In this case you have to set the problem's constraint so $\sigma(3)=2$ it's not allowed, but $\sigma(3)=3$, $\sigma(3)=1$ and $\sigma(3)=5$ are. You have to count all these different situations.

Comment: @Karl $ S_5$ is the group of all possible permutations of the elements $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$

Comment: If $\sigma\in S_5$, then $\sigma(\{2,4\})=\{2,4\}$ iff $\sigma(\{1,3,5\})=\{1,3,5\}$.

Comment: For example, $\sigma=(24)(35)$ does it, or $(24)(15)$, or $(24)(135)$, or $(135)$, or ...

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes here. There's a clear attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so we need a bijection from $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ to itself. Also, importantly, we need to send $2$ and $4$ to $2$ and $4$, and we don't care about where $1,3,5$ are sent. You can send $2$  to $2$ or you can send $2$ to $4$, and in these cases you have to send $4$ to $4$ or $2$ respectively. There are $3!$ ways to arrange $1,3,5$, and hence $3!$ bijections which do the rearrangement. So, $2$ possibilities for where $2$ and $4$ go, and $3!$ possibilities for where $1,3,5$ go. In total that is $2\cdot 3!=12$ total bijections.

Answer (score 1):

Let $H$ be the subgroup of $S_5$ of elements that fix the elements of $\{1,3,5\}$. Let $K$ be the subgroup of $S_5$ of elements that fix the elements of $\{2,4\}$. (These are clearly subgroups by transfer of structure onto $S_2$ and $S_3$ respectively.)

We have:

- $H\cap K=\{e\}$.
- For all $h\in H, k\in K$, $$hk=kh.$$

Thus $H\times K$ is isomorphic to an internal direct product $H\otimes K$ in $S_5$.

The elements of $H\otimes K$ contain all and only those elements of $S_5$ that send $\{2,4\}$ to $\{2,4\}$; $H$, in particular, clearly does this, and elements of $K$ leave $\{2,4\}$ untouched.

Thus the number you are after is

$$\begin{align}
|H\times K|&=|H||K|\\
&=|S_2||S_3|\\
&=2\times 3!\\
&=12.
\end{align}$$